# js template engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, template

I am building a template engine for js and I need some help refactoring the code for fast and more efficient performance. If you can help modify or suggest some updates I'll be grateful.

```
var TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_REGISTER = new(function ContextRegister() {})();
var TEMPLATE_HELPERS_REGISTER = new(function HelpersRegister() {})();
var TEMPLATE_COMMENT_TYPE = Symbol.for("COMMENT");
var TEMPLATE_INIRIAL_TYPE = Symbol.for("INIRIAL");
var TEMPLATE_SEGMENT_TYPE = Symbol.for("SEGMENT");
var TEMPLATE_EXCLUDE_CHARS = "@";
var TEMPLATE_COMMENT_CHARS = ["(#", "#)"];
var TEMPLATE_CONTENT_CHARS = ["{{", "}}"];
var TEMPLATE_SEGMENT_CHARS = ["($", "$)"];
var TEMPLATE_REGEX_QUOTE = "(?=(?:[^'\"`]|[\"'`][^'\"`]*[\"'`])*$)";
var TEMPLATE_REGEX_START = TEMPLATE_SEGMENT_CHARS[0].replace(/(\(|\$)/g, "\\$1");
var TEMPLATE_REGEX_CLOSE = TEMPLATE_SEGMENT_CHARS[1].replace(/(\$|\))/g, "\\$1");
var TEMPLATE_REGEX_HELPER = [new RegExp("(@)" + TEMPLATE_REGEX_QUOTE, "g"), "$TEMPLATEHELPERS."];
var TEMPLATE_REGEX_COURSE = [new RegExp("(@loop)" + TEMPLATE_REGEX_QUOTE, "g"), "$TEMPLATELOOP"];
var TEMPLATE_REGEX_FACTOR = [new RegExp("(@this)" + TEMPLATE_REGEX_QUOTE, "g"), "$TEMPLATETHIS"];
var TEMPLATE_REGEX_SCRIPT = [
    new RegExp(TEMPLATE_REGEX_START + "script" + TEMPLATE_REGEX_CLOSE + "([\\s\\S]*?)" + TEMPLATE_REGEX_START + "/script" + TEMPLATE_REGEX_CLOSE, "gmi"),
    function(_, code) {
        return TEMPLATE_SEGMENT_CHARS[0] + "script " + code.replace(/\s\s+|\n/g, "") + TEMPLATE_SEGMENT_CHARS[1];
    },
];
var TEMPLATE_REGEX_ESCAPE = [
    new RegExp("s*(</?[ws=\"/.':;#-/?]+>)s*", "gi"),
    function(_, i) {
        return i.trim();
    },
];
var TEMPLATE_REGEX_OBJECT = [
    new RegExp("([.]+[\\w\\d-_]+)" + TEMPLATE_REGEX_QUOTE, "g"),
    function(obj) {
        return "['" + obj.substring(1) + "']";
    },
];

function _tpl_include_(partial, context, txtarr, jsxarr, index) {
    var template = new Template(partial, context);
    var jsx = _build_({ origins: template.origins, context: template.context, helpers: template.helpers, partial: template.partial }),
        txt = jsx.shift();
    txtarr = [].concat(txtarr, [txtarr.pop() + txt.shift()], txt);
    jsxarr = [].concat(jsxarr, jsx);
    return [txtarr, jsxarr, index + jsx.length];
}

function _tpl_length_(object) {
    return Array.isArray(object) ? object.length : typeof object === "object" ? Object.keys(object).length : null;
}

function _tpl_range_(from, to, inc, func) {
    to = inc ? (from < to ? to + 1 : to - 1) : to;
    for (var i = from; from < to ? i < to : i > to; from < to ? i++ : i--) {
        func(i, {
            index: i,
            round: i + 1,
            odd: i % 2 > 0,
            even: i % 2 === 0,
            first: i === from,
            last: i === from < to ? i - 1 : i + 1,
        });
    }
}

function _tpl_each_(obj, func) {
    if (obj === null) {
        return obj;
    }
    var index = -1;
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        var length = obj.length,
            count = 1;
        while (++index < length) {
            if (
                func(index, obj[index], {
                    index: index,
                    round: count,
                    odd: index % 2 > 0,
                    even: index % 2 === 0,
                    first: index === 0,
                    last: count === length,
                }) === false
            ) {
                break;
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
    var key = Object.keys(obj),
        length = key.length,
        count = 1;
    while (++index < length) {
        if (
            func(key[index], obj[key[index]], {
                index: index,
                round: count,
                odd: index % 2 > 0,
                even: index % 2 === 0,
                first: index === 0,
                last: count === length,
            }) === false
        ) {
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }
}

function _loops_args_(args) {
    var mth = /\[(.*),(.*)\]/g.exec(args[1]),
        arr = args[0].trim(),
        val = args[1].trim(),
        key = "_";
    return [arr, mth ? mth[1].trim() : key, mth ? mth[2].trim() : val];
}

function _range_args_(args) {
    var mth = /(.*)\s*(:?to|via)\s*(.*)/g.exec(args[1]),
        arr = args[0].trim();
    return [arr, mth[1].trim(), mth[3].trim(), mth[2].trim() === "via"];
}

function _replace_(line, ...regexArray) {
    for (var i = 0, len = regexArray.length; i < len; i++) {
        var regex = regexArray[i][0],
            replace = regexArray[i][1];
        line = line.replace(regex, replace);
    }
    return line;
}

function _token_(type, value, ln, cl) {
    return {
        type,
        value: type === TEMPLATE_SEGMENT_TYPE ? _logic_(value, ln, cl) : value,
        ln,
        cl,
    };
}

function _check_(source, niddle, index) {
    return niddle.split("").every((e, i) => source[index + i] === e);
}

function _logic_(source, ln, cl) {
    var args = _replace_(source, TEMPLATE_REGEX_COURSE, TEMPLATE_REGEX_FACTOR, TEMPLATE_REGEX_HELPER, TEMPLATE_REGEX_OBJECT).split(" "),
        curs = "$TEMPLATELINNO=" + ln + ";$TEMPLATECOLNO=" + cl + ";",
        line = args.slice(1).join(" "),
        type = args[0];
    switch (type) {
        case "log":
        case "info":
        case "warn":
        case "error":
        case "debug":
            return "console." + type + "(" + line + ");" + curs;
        case "echo":
            return "$TEMPLATEJSXOF(" + line + ");" + curs;
        case "raw":
            return "$TEMPLATETXTOF(" + line + ");" + curs;
        case "set":
            return "var " + line + ";" + curs;
        case "elif":
            return "}else if(" + line + "){" + curs;
        case "else":
            return "}else{" + curs;
        case "empty":
            return "});}else{" + curs;
        case "script":
            return line + curs;
        case "include":
            var [partial, context] = line.split("with");
            return (
                "[$TEMPLATETXTAR,$TEMPLATEJSXAR,$TEMPLATEINDEX]=$TEMPLATEINCLUDE(" +
                partial +
                "," +
                context +
                ",$TEMPLATETXTAR,$TEMPLATEJSXAR,$TEMPLATEINDEX);" +
                curs
            );
        case "each":
            var [arr, key, val] = _loops_args_(line.split("as"));
            return "$TEMPLATEEACH(" + arr + ",function(" + key + "," + val + ", $TEMPLATELOOP){" + curs;
        case "range":
            var [arr, from, to, is] = _range_args_(line.split("from"));
            return "$TEMPLATERANGE(" + from + "," + to + "," + is + ",function(" + arr + ", $TEMPLATELOOP){" + curs;
        case "/each":
        case "/range":
            return "});" + curs;
        case "if":
            return "if(" + line + "){" + curs;
        case "unless":
            return "if(!(" + line + ")){" + curs;
        case "until":
            return "while(!(" + line + ")){" + curs;
        case "while":
            return "while(" + line + "){" + curs;
        case "forelse":
            var [arr, key, val] = _loops_args_(line.split("as"));
            return "if($TEMPLATELENGTH(" + arr + ")){$TEMPLATEEACH(" + arr + ",function(" + key + "," + val + ", $TEMPLATELOOP){" + curs;
        case "/if":
        case "/unless":
        case "/until":
        case "/while":
        case "/forelse":
            return "}" + curs;
        default:
            return "";
    }
}

function _parse_(source) {
    var ln = 1,
        cl = 1,
        dt = [],
        al = "",
        cu = "",
        op = false;

    for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        cl++;
        if (source[i] === "\n")(cl = 1), ln++;
        if (_check_(source, TEMPLATE_EXCLUDE_CHARS + TEMPLATE_COMMENT_CHARS[0], i)) {
            if (cu !== "") {
                al += cu + TEMPLATE_COMMENT_CHARS[0];
                cu = "";
            }
            op = false;
            i = i + TEMPLATE_COMMENT_CHARS[0].length;
        } else if (_check_(source, TEMPLATE_EXCLUDE_CHARS + TEMPLATE_SEGMENT_CHARS[0], i)) {
            if (cu !== "") {
                al += cu + TEMPLATE_SEGMENT_CHARS[0];
                cu = "";
            }
            op = false;
            i = i + TEMPLATE_SEGMENT_CHARS[0].length;
        } else if (_check_(source, TEMPLATE_EXCLUDE_CHARS + TEMPLATE_CONTENT_CHARS[0], i)) {
            if (cu !== "") {
                al += cu + TEMPLATE_CONTENT_CHARS[0];
                cu = "";
            }
            op = false;
            i = i + TEMPLATE_CONTENT_CHARS[0].length;
        } else if (
            _check_(source, TEMPLATE_COMMENT_CHARS[0], i) ||
            _check_(source, TEMPLATE_SEGMENT_CHARS[0], i) ||
            _check_(source, TEMPLATE_CONTENT_CHARS[0], i)
        ) {
            var plus =
                (_check_(source, TEMPLATE_COMMENT_CHARS[0], i) ?
                    TEMPLATE_COMMENT_CHARS[0] :
                    _check_(source, TEMPLATE_SEGMENT_CHARS[0], i) ?
                    TEMPLATE_SEGMENT_CHARS[0] :
                    TEMPLATE_CONTENT_CHARS[0]
                ).length - 1;
            if (cu !== "") {
                if (_check_(source, TEMPLATE_COMMENT_CHARS[0], i)) al += cu;
                else {
                    dt.push(_token_(TEMPLATE_INIRIAL_TYPE, al + cu, ln, cl + plus));
                    al = "";
                }
                cu = "";
            }
            op = true;
            i = i + plus;
        } else if (_check_(source, TEMPLATE_COMMENT_CHARS[1], i)) {
            var plus = TEMPLATE_COMMENT_CHARS[1].length - 1;
            if (op) {
                dt.push(_token_(TEMPLATE_COMMENT_TYPE, cu.trim(), ln, cl + plus));
            } else {
                al += cu + TEMPLATE_COMMENT_CHARS[1];
            }
            cu = "";
            op = false;
            i = i + plus;
        } else if (_check_(source, TEMPLATE_SEGMENT_CHARS[1], i)) {
            var plus = TEMPLATE_SEGMENT_CHARS[1].length - 1;
            if (op) {
                dt.push(_token_(TEMPLATE_SEGMENT_TYPE, cu.trim(), ln, cl + plus));
            } else {
                al += cu + TEMPLATE_SEGMENT_CHARS[1];
            }
            cu = "";
            op = false;
            i = i + plus;
        } else if (_check_(source, TEMPLATE_CONTENT_CHARS[1], i)) {
            var plus = TEMPLATE_CONTENT_CHARS[1].length - 1;
            if (op) {
                dt.push(_token_(TEMPLATE_SEGMENT_TYPE, cu.trim()[0] === ">" ? "raw " + cu.trim().slice(1) : "echo " + cu.trim(), ln, cl + plus));
            } else {
                al += cu + TEMPLATE_CONTENT_CHARS[1];
            }
            cu = "";
            op = false;
            i = i + plus;
        } else {
            cu += source[i];
        }
    }
    dt.push(_token_(TEMPLATE_INIRIAL_TYPE, al + cu, ln + 1, cl + 1));
    return dt;
}

function _compile_(source) {
    var exe = _parse_(source);
    var txt = exe.filter((e) => e.type === TEMPLATE_INIRIAL_TYPE);
    var jsx = exe.filter((e) => e.type === TEMPLATE_SEGMENT_TYPE);
    return Array.from({ length: Math.max(txt.length, jsx.length) }, function(_, i) {
        return i;
    }).reduce(function(acc, idx) {
        var jx = jsx[idx] || { value: "" },
            tx = txt[idx] || { value: "", ln: -1, cl: -1 };
        return (acc += "$TEMPLATETXTOF(`" + tx.value + "`);$TEMPLATELINNO=" + tx.ln + ";$TEMPLATECOLNO=" + tx.cl + ";" + jx.value);
    }, "");
}

function _bind_(object) {
    for (var name in TEMPLATE_HELPERS_REGISTER)
        if (
            typeof TEMPLATE_HELPERS_REGISTER[name] === "function" &&
            !/^(?:class\s+|function\s+(?:_class|_default|[A-Z]))/.test(TEMPLATE_HELPERS_REGISTER[name])
        )
            TEMPLATE_HELPERS_REGISTER[name] = TEMPLATE_HELPERS_REGISTER[name].bind(object);
        else delete TEMPLATE_HELPERS_REGISTER[name];
}

function _build_({ origins, context, helpers, partial }) {
    if (!variables._VCS_[partial]) variables._VCS_[partial] = _compile_(origins);
    var exe =
        "return function($TEMPLATETHIS,$TEMPLATEHELPERS,$TEMPLATEINCLUDE,$TEMPLATELENGTH,$TEMPLATERANGE,$TEMPLATEEACH,$TEMPLATEERROR){var $TEMPLATETXTAR=[],$TEMPLATEJSXAR=[],$TEMPLATEINDEX=0,$TEMPLATELINNO=0,$TEMPLATECOLNO=0;function $TEMPLATEESCAPE($LINE){var $MAP={'&':'&amp;','<':'&lt;','>':'&gt;','\"':'&quot;','\\'':'&#39;'};return typeof $LINE!=='string'?$LINE:$LINE.replace(/[&<>\"']/g,function($CHAR){return $MAP[$CHAR];});}function $TEMPLATETXTOF($LINE){if(!$TEMPLATETXTAR[$TEMPLATEINDEX]){$TEMPLATETXTAR[$TEMPLATEINDEX]='';}$TEMPLATETXTAR[$TEMPLATEINDEX]+=$LINE;}function $TEMPLATEJSXOF($LINE){$TEMPLATEJSXAR[$TEMPLATEINDEX]=$TEMPLATEESCAPE($LINE);$TEMPLATEINDEX++;}with($TEMPLATETHIS||{}){try{" +
        variables._VCS_[partial] +
        "}catch(e){throw new $TEMPLATEERROR(e.message+'\\nview: " +
        partial +
        "\\nline: '+$TEMPLATELINNO+'\\npos: '+$TEMPLATECOLNO);}}return [$TEMPLATETXTAR.map(function(txt){return txt.replace(/\\n+|\\n\\s+/g, '\\n')}),...$TEMPLATEJSXAR];}";
    return new Function("", exe)()(context, helpers, _tpl_include_, _tpl_length_, _tpl_range_, _tpl_each_, CurseError);
}

function Template(partial, context) {
    if (!(partial in variables._VMS_)) throw new CurseError('view "' + partial + '" not found');
    this.origins = _replace_(variables._VMS_[partial], TEMPLATE_REGEX_SCRIPT, TEMPLATE_REGEX_ESCAPE, [/ {2,}/g, " "]);
    this.context = {...TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_REGISTER, ...(context || {}) };
    this.helpers = _bind_(this.context);
    this.partial = partial;
}

Template.prototype.exec = function() {
    var template = _build_({ origins: this.origins, context: this.context, helpers: this.helpers, partial: this.partial });
    return new Parser(...template).exec();
};

Template.prototype.string = function() {
    var template = _build_({ origins: this.origins, context: this.context, helpers: this.helpers, partial: this.partial });
    return template.shift().reduce(function(acc, part, i) {
        return acc + part + (["string", "number", "boolean"].includes(typeof template[i]) ? template[i] : "");
    }, "");
};

function TemplateRegister() {}

TemplateRegister.prototype.helper = function(name, callback) {
    if (name in TEMPLATE_HELPERS_REGISTER) throw new CurseError("Helper " + name + " already exists.");
    TEMPLATE_HELPERS_REGISTER[name] = callback;
};

TemplateRegister.prototype.context = function(name, value) {
    if (name in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_REGISTER) throw new CurseError("Context " + name + " already exists.");
    TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_REGISTER[name] = value;
};

Template.register = new TemplateRegister();
```

Comment: It would benefit reviewers to have a bit more information about the code in the description. From [the help center page _How to ask_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask): "_You will get more insightful reviews if you not only provide your code, but also give an explanation of what it does. The more detail, the better._" Obviously it is a template engine but perhaps sample usage would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

### Style

Some style points.

- JS does not use `snake_case` naming, try to use the JS style `camelCase` naming. We only use underscore when naming constants in allcaps.
- Why all the post and pre script underscores? eg `function _token_(` I can not see any need and thus its just noise.
- Use constants for variables that do not change. Eg `var TEMPLATE_COMMENT_CHARS = ["(#", "#)"];` should be `const TEMPLATE_COMMENT_CHARS = ["(#", "#)"];`
- If you find that you are prefixing many variables with the same name, its a sure sign that you should encapsulate those variables in an object.
  Eg you have many names starting with `TEMPLATE_` as in

  > ```
  >   var TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_REGISTER = new(function ContextRegister() {})();
  >   var TEMPLATE_HELPERS_REGISTER = new(function HelpersRegister() {})();
  >   var TEMPLATE_COMMENT_TYPE = Symbol.for("COMMENT");
  >   var TEMPLATE_INIRIAL_TYPE = Symbol.for("INIRIAL");
  >   var TEMPLATE_SEGMENT_TYPE = Symbol.for("SEGMENT");
  >   ... // and so on
  > ```

  Can be

  ```
  const TEMPLATE = Object.freeze({
     contextRegister: new(function ContextRegister() {})(),
     helpersRegister: new(function HelpersRegister() {})(),
     commentType: Symbol.for("COMMENT"),
     inirialType: Symbol.for("INIRIAL"),
     segmentType: Symbol.for("SEGMENT"),
     ... // and so on
  ```

  the `Object.freeze(` ensures that the objects' content can not be changed.
- Always delimit code blocks with `{}`
  Example you have

  > ```
  > if (_check_(source, TEMPLATE_COMMENT_CHARS[0], i)) al += cu;
  > else {
  >     dt.push(_token_(TEMPLATE_INIRIAL_TYPE, al + cu, ln, cl + plus));
  >     al = "";
  > }
  > ```

  much better as...

  ```
       if (check(source, TEMPLATE.commentChars[0], i)) { 
           al += cu;
       } else {
           dt.push(token(TEMPLATE.inirialType, al + cu, ln, cl + plus));
           al = "";
       }
  ```
- Way too many short unreadable names

  Example

  > ```
  > var ln = 1,
  >     cl = 1,
  >     dt = [],
  >     al = "",
  >     cu = "",
  >     op = false;
  > ```
- Keep long complex clauses out of statements.

  Example you have

  > ```
  >     if (
  >         func(key[index], obj[key[index]], {
  >             index: index,
  >             round: count,
  >             odd: index % 2 > 0,
  >             even: index % 2 === 0,
  >             first: index === 0,
  >             last: count === length,
  >         }) === false
  >     ) {
  > ```

  Move the expression out of the statement and assign to a variable, test the variable. Only if the expression is more than a line.

  ```
       // I have no clue what this does, and thus the name "test"
       // Using a descriptive name would help the code a lot.
       const test = func(key[index], obj[key[index]], {
           index: index,
           round: count,
           odd: index % 2 > 0,
           even: index % 2 === 0,
           first: index === 0,
           last: count === length,
       });
       if (!test) {
  ```
- Use modern syntax.

  Example...

  > ```
  > for (var i = 0, len = regexArray.length; i < len; i++) {
  >     var regex = regexArray[i][0],
  >         replace = regexArray[i][1];
  >     line = line.replace(regex, replace);
  > }
  > ```

  Can use a `for of` loop

  ```
   for (const regexp of regexArray) {
       const regex = regexp[0];
       const replace = regexp[1];
       line = line.replace(regex, replace);
   }
  ```

  Or no need for the single use variable declaration...

  ```
   for (const regexp of regexArray) {
       line = line.replace(regexp[0], regexp[1]);
   }
  ```

  Or use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the first two items of each sub array;;

  ```
   for (const [regex, replace] of regexArray) {
       line = line.replace(regex, replace);
   }
  ```

  See next section Design for some more usage of modern JS syntax.

  - BTW

    Modern JS engines optimise loops, thus capturing the length is now unneeded overhead, as in...

    > ```
    >  for (var i = 0, len = regexArray.length; i < len; i++) {
    > ```

    with the following running ever so slightly faster,

    ```
    for (var i = 0; i < regexArray.length; i++) {
    ```

---

### Design

You have long complex switch statements.

JS does not optimise switch statements and thus the time complexity of switch statements is \$O(n)\$, where n is the number of cases.

Consider using an object to map the names you test in the switch statement. The map will hash the expression (`type` in `switch(type)`) and then find the correct case in the ideal \$O(1)\$ time.

**Note:** that there is an overhead for the hashing function. This design optimization is only worthwhile for switch statements with many cases.

Example from your code...

> ```
> switch (type) {
>     case "error":
>     case "debug":
>         return "console." + type + "(" + line + ");" + curs;
>     case "echo":
>         return "$TEMPLATEJSXOF(" + line + ");" + curs;
>     case "raw":
>         return "$TEMPLATETXTOF(" + line + ");" + curs;
>     case "set":
>         return "var " + line + ";" + curs;
>     case "elif":
>         return "}else if(" + line + "){" + curs;
>     case "else":   
>  ... // and so on
>     default:
>         return "";
> }
> ```

can be written as...

```
const logsCommon = (type, line, curs) => `console.${type}(${ line });${ curs }`;
const PARSER = {
    error: logsCommon,
    debug: logsCommon,
    echo:     (type, line, curs) => `$\TEMPLATEJSXOF(${ line });${ curs }`,
    raw:      (type, line, curs) => `$\TEMPLATETXTOF(${ line });${ curs }`,
    ["set"]:  (type, line, curs) => `var ${ line };${ curs }`,
    elif:     (type, line, curs) => `}else if(${ line }){${ curs }`,
    ["else"]: (type, line, curs) => 
    ... // and so on
```

The switch statement thus becomes

```
  return PARSER[type]?.(type, line, curs) ?? "";
```

**Note:** that tokens and non-names can be added using bracket notation.

**Note:** the use of [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) AKA (Template strings).

**Note:** use of [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

**Note:** use of [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to call the function `PARSER[type]?.`

**Note:**  use of [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) the  `?? ""` returns the default if the expression `PARSER[type]?.(type, line, curs)` evaluates to `undefined` or `null`